# Opencart SEO URL not working properly

Tags: url-rewriting, opencart2.x

All the category links appear like this in Opencart version 2.1

```
http://localhost/jahangirkhalid/desktops/pc
```

but there are only three categories that appear in the old way

```
http://localhost/jahangirkhalid/?/index.php?_route_=desktops/mac
http://localhost/jahangirkhalid/?/index.php?_route_=laptop-notebook/macs
http://localhost/jahangirkhalid/?/index.php?_route_=laptop-notebook/windows
```

What could the problem be.

Comment: adding a few more letters to the SEO Keywords fixes this problem, Ijust found this out. Like Changing Mac to Mactwo fixes the Mac category. And so on. But is there any proper solution for this problem?

Comment: please read & follow this tutorials. http://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/opencart2/seo-urls